# Files cannot read by my Ajax after reading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

im using an API to pass a whole form including images, textarea, etc.

it uses `new FormData($('#form'))` to pass the data into server.

everything went smooth except when i did something on `<input type="file" id="upload"/>`

I made the input to show the image every time the user uploads a new photo.

```
$(function() {
$("#upload").on("change", function()
{
    var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
    if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support

    if (/^image/.test( files[0].type)){ // only image file
        var reader = new FileReader(); // instance of the FileReader
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); // read the local file

        reader.onloadend = function(){ // set image data as background of div
             //Showing the images here..
        }
    }
});
});
```

But now, when im submitting the form again using Ajax, it cannot read or pass the image. No image passed in the database.

Whenever i comment the line `//var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];` its back to normal, but the image is not showing.

i want to ask is there an alternate way to show the image without affecting the `<input type="file"` tag?

Or if i have to create another `<input type="file"` with `style="display: none;"`, how can i pass the image from one input with type="file" to another input with also type="file"?